# If is true for Cell do something on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Data:

```
DF1

first   second  third 
   0      5       0        

   0      0       0      

   1      0       0       

   0      0       3
```

```
DF 2

Final Price
```

```
df_price

100

20

40

10
```

```
firstPrice = (df_1['first'] == 0)
secondPrice = (df_1['second'] == 0)
thirdPrice = (df_1['third'] == 0)

if (firstPrice & secondPrice & thirdPrice):
    price = "free"

else:
    price = df_prices['price']
df_2['Final Price'] = price
```

The problem is that I get this:

```
Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

I know the structure sounds dumb, but I have to do it this way.

So basically, if the first, second and third are not equal to 0, we are going to get the finalprice on the df_price table. If it's zero, the final price table will be "free"

Comment: What specifically is your question? For us to help you, provide a minimal reproducible problem set containing sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. What you have provided falls short of this goal. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: Sorry, let me fix this!!

Comment: I think you're looking for `df_2['Final Price'] = np.where(firstPrice & secondPrice & thirdPrice, "free", df_prices['price']);` _instead of_ the if else.

Comment: Henry, that was exactly it, I was mumbling thru np.where but I finally got it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In python, `&` is bitwise and. If you want to compare booleans, you use `and`. That would be:

```py
if firstPrice and secondPrice and thirdPrice:
```

Comment: I tried with both, and get the same error.